# xpath to get text inside the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, xpath, mechanize-ruby

I have an HTML structure of a page like this,

```
<form align="center" method="post" name="form1">
<input type="hidden" value="J0512-0491" name="jobid">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="BDID">

<br>
<hr>
<b>Category: </b>
Food & Beverage
<br>
<b>City: </b>
Carlyle, Saskatchewan, Canada
<br>
<b>Job Number: </b>
05012-04191
<br>
<b>Salary Range: </b>
$13.19 - 16.48
<br>
<b>Closing Date: </b>
31/03/2013
<br>
<hr>
<b></b>
```

I need to extract the text of "City:" i.e "Carlyne,Saskatchewan,Canada" using the xpath.
any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: This is an invalid XML! It has got uncoded characters like `&` and tags aren't closed.. This looks like an HTML but you should close tags ..

Comment: Well I have included just a part of html not included all the page's html:)

Comment: okay! Let me ask you this where are you going to use XPATH ?? in XSLT? or C# (XML DOM)? like where?

Comment: I am extracting the page's content using ruby mechanize parser, and used  //*[contains(text(),'City')] but its selecting only the <br>tag but not the text below it

Comment: You should insert text inside tags. For instance : `<b>City</b><span>Carlyle, Saskatchewan, Canada</span>`

Comment: yes but what about this case where text is not associated with tags? like in this link http://clients.njoyn.com/CGI/xweb/XWeb.asp?tbtoken=ZVBQDVArNhx3awZ5REhcE1NKbWArdCRBAyYnVUV4C20pK0JoWUUfemo4P0ZQVxVWB3E%3D&chk=dFlbQBJc&Page=JobDetails&Jobid=J0512-0491&clid=25304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//*[contains(text(),'City')]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: It is selecting all the siblings <br> tags text, what needs to be done if I want exclude the remaining text fields?

Comment: does it work? `//*[contains(text(),'City')]/following-sibling::text()[1]`

Comment: yes @Charles-EdouardCoste it works! you can put this under the answer so that I can accept it